# Executing successful 'git pull' on virtual machine but not on a hosted live server, what could be the issue?

Tags: php, git

I have a problem with git pull command on a server. I successfully managed to do it on my own virtual machine but it doesn't work on a live server.

This server is hosted by external company and I don't have any access to a terminal and I can't get any good output from exec commands in PHP.

I want to be able to update a website using git pull. As mentioned before I was able to do it on virtual machine. The command that I'm using is:

```
$local = exec('git rev-parse HEAD');

$remote_raw = exec("git ls-remote https://user:credential@github.com/repository.git HEAD");

$remote = substr($remote_raw,0,-5);

if($local !== $remote){
    exec("git pull https://user:credential@github.com/repository.git main");
}
```

It properly works till the git pull. I can get some output of this command and it only says that it is updating but no file changes and the next time I run this it just does everything as before.

I tried to find a solution but wasn't able so risked asking for it here.

Perhaps the problem is with permissions on the server? Is this what I'm trying to do possible with external hosting?

I will appreciate any hint.

Comment: Lots of hosting companies will give you terminal access. If you want to do stuff like this, I suggest migrating to one which gives better support for the features you need.

Comment: If they wont let you have a terminal, then its quite likely they didnt bother installing or giving a site access to git. What woudl be the point

Comment: You are really asking for trouble trying to manage git using a PHP-based script. I'm not saying it is impossible, but I can think of so many things that could go disastrously wrong. "I don't have any access to a terminal" - they might not have provided this, so maybe it is as simple as asking. If it isn't a feature they support, then I agree, there are other hosts that would support this. If they block this for security reasons, maybe you just need to get a VPN profile, or ask if they have an SSH jump/proxy server available, they're very easy and fast to setup.